# Hidden Parameter is missing a value

Tags: ssrs-2012

In my report, i have created a xxx parameter which takes values from the report data set.

xxx parameter is not being passed to stored proc which is used to show the data for the report.

Now When the report does not have any data for other parameters, i get an error saying xxx parameter is missing a value.

I tried allowing blank values in the parameter properties.

Comment: You need to default the value to something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that parameter's - Available Values by going to report parameters properties.
It must not be specified any values. So we should set it as None

Another way is,
Just add a blank space at Specify values - in Default values inside report parameters properties.

Third way

Ido an "if exists" statement for this to go away. It worked for me because it makes it always return a value even if that value is not need by my query.
    if exists (my select query)
    my select query
    else 
    select '2' 
    // '2' would never be used, but it made ssrs stop giving me
    // the stupid error and execute

This should help.

Comment: thanks for your respond. I had already tried both suggestion but still facing the same  issue.

Comment: Updated the answer try third way

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Yes, this i had already tried and indeed this is a workaround. But cant we handle it from the report itself without modifying the data set.